# System.NotSupportedException: Can't call read method while there's a pending read operation. How to avoid?

Tags: c#, stream, imap

I'm modifying an IMAP library due to an error, here's the code:

```
internal static string ReadLine(this Stream stream, ref int maxLength, Encoding encoding, char? termChar, int ReadTimeout = 10000) {
        if (stream.CanTimeout)
            stream.ReadTimeout = ReadTimeout;

        var maxLengthSpecified = maxLength > 0;
        int i;
        byte b = 0, b0;
        var read = false;
        using (var mem = new MemoryStream()) {
            while (true) {
                b0 = b;
                
                i = stream.ReadByte(); //Error pops here
                if (i == -1) break;
                else read = true;

                b = (byte)i;
                if (maxLengthSpecified) maxLength--;

                if (maxLengthSpecified && mem.Length == 1 && b == termChar && b0 == termChar) {
                    maxLength++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (b == 10 || b == 13) {
                    if (mem.Length == 0 && b == 10) {
                        continue;
                    } else break;
                }

                mem.WriteByte(b);
                if (maxLengthSpecified && maxLength == 0)
                    break;
            }

            if (mem.Length == 0 && !read) return null;
            return encoding.GetString(mem.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

This function is from Nuget Package AE.NET.MAIL. All i need to know is if there's a way to handle "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.dll
The Read method cannot be called when another read operation is pending."

Comment: Are you trying to share the Stream between threads?  (Or the higher level objects?)

Comment: The stream is shared in threads if that helps. (I really have no experience with that)

Comment: Simple answer: don't do that.  A network connection can only be meaningfully used by one thread at a time.